# File Naming Pattern within import on seconds

Tags: marketing-cloud, import, pattern

I have a Import that uses the File Naming Pattern `etsync_%%Year%%%%Month%%%%Day%%%%Hour%%%%Minute%%%%Second%%.csv` and it is used in a Triggered Automation, would the Automation be fast enough to trigger and see the timestamp within the same second, and then recognize it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are speaking of Triggered automation, it should trigger in the order that they are dropped if you enable file queuing.

What is the need for the second-level granularity?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with David Jackman - if you need that level of granularity, you're overloading your import directory. It's better to just add new `File Location` subdirs if you're worried about collisions.

Anyway, beyond the Starting Source (the "File Drop," which should be scoped to whatever subdir/filename pattern you want), just use `%%BASEFILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%%.csv` for everything (`File Transfer` and `Import File` activities). The web UI will warn you of "No file matching ...", but you can just ignore that - it works perfectly.

Here's a picture that might illustrate the point a little better (pardon the dark theme).

[image: Import definition reusable file pattern example]